# Extract value from XML using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to extract the value from the below XML using XSLT 1.0. Can you please advise the xslt code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<title>
 <locale>
<properties>
  <OriginalFileName>UMG_00720616207322_T3_locale.uti</OriginalFileName>      
</properties>
</locale>
</title>
```

**Desired output**

720616207322

Comment: Where is the XSLT code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression:

```
substring-before(substring-after($string, '_'), '_')
```

will return "00720616207322" when $string contains "UMG_00720616207322_T3_locale.uti".